# How to test interaction of micro-services in gitlab ci?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, gitlab-ci

I have 4 services that are all NodeJS API's, 1 is the 'main-service' and I want to test the routing between the services.

Locally I can do that, I start up the other 3 services and run the test and they succeed.
Now I want to do the same thing, only on gitlab ci, but I can't figure out how.

I have build 4 docker images of the services and in test I pull them all, run the other 3 detached and run the 4th with the test command, but all the routing test fail with for example: `'RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:9016'`.
Locally when I set the adresses of the services with docker it works, but it looks like I can't reach them in gitlab ci.

Anyone an idea of how to do this?

Comment: In GitLab-CI you can run "services" (which is roughly the equivalent to sidecar containeres in Jenkins). These services are docker containers. You could spin up your microservices as GitLab-services and should then be able to run your tests.

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/
Also note the naming of the services, you will probably have to pass those as environment variables to your service

Comment: hmm I tried it, but the services are dependend on mongo and they cannot connect if I start them via the services